# Custom Search Option in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site in my local pc.
Now I want to add custom search option with a combobox with different items such as: Most viewed posts, recently posted, most comments posts etc.

I will select a option from the combobox and click search/find button.
Then it show result base on the selected value.
How can I build the functionality any idea.... ??

Answer (score 0):

you can pass to WP_Query()  's' => $searchterm as well as 'orderby' => 'comment_count'( for most comments ) or 'orderby' => 'date' or 'modified' ( for recent  ).

for most viewed, check this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25645/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-popular-posts-by-views)